# finding a substring in regex excel / vba

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have very long string with a particular pattern. similar to the following:

> AG156 fox is the animal AG156 cat is a pet AG156 stars are in the sky
>   AG156 Roses + red.

There may be line breaks at any point. I want to return words between "AG156" and "red" but only the AG156 immediately before red.

**Desired result**

"AG156 Roses + red".

How do I this with regex? Currently my expressions returns everything between the first AG156 and red.

Thanks!

Comment: it would help to have your current expression. My guess is you are missing a `?` to make it non-greedy

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regular expressions used in VBA doesn't support lookbehinds IIRC. So, you can use this pattern `(?:.|\n)*(AG156(?:.|\n)*?red)`. The first `(?:.|\n)*` needs to **be greedy** to consume all the other `AG156`, else making it non-greedy will match everything between the *first* **AG156** to the word **red**. The second `(?:.|\n)*?` should be **non-greedy** to match up to the first occurrence of the word **red**.

```
Sub test()

    Dim retVal As String, inputStr As String

    inputStr = "AG156 fox is the animal AG156 cat is a pet AG156 stars are " & _
            "in the sky AG156 Roses + red."

    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "(?:.|\n)*(AG156(?:.|\n)*?red)"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        retVal = .Execute(inputStr)(0).SubMatches(0)
    End With

    Debug.Print retVal
    ' Prints the string: "AG156 Roses + red"

End Sub
```

If you prefer late-binding your regex object, replace this line:

```
With New RegExp
```

with this:

```
with createobject("VBScript.RegExp")
```

Comment: Hi,
When i run this code it returns the whole string: 

AG156 fox is the animal AG156 cat is a pet AG156 stars are in the sky AG156 Roses + red.

Which is my problem. I only want. 

 AG156 Roses + red

I don't think ".*AG156" does the trick.

Comment: When I ran it it only returned ` Roses + `. Can you show me an example that may include any line breaks in your statement?

Comment: Even [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HJYISX/1) pattern is matching as intended. Why don't you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52998355/edit) your question showing the code you have used thus far.

Comment: I am confused. When I follow the regex101 link it shows the whole line as highlighted (full match in blue). This is not the correct result. There is a group 1 which shows "Roses +" in green but that is also not the correct result.

In regex101 it should only be "AG156 Roses + red" highlighted regardless of linebreaks.

Comment: @Kantoboy The blue is not what is being returned. The blue is simply the first `.*` portion of the code. It would be the green that would be what is returned. And I am not sure how that green match is not correct since you are asking for everything between the last `AG156` and the word `red`. And [here is another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFsgZ.gif) of it returning everything between those two words.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. If you wanted to include `AG156` and the word `red` as well, then you would simply move the capturing group to consume those words. Update coming in a quick second. -- Here is the [new regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HJYISX/2) showing the match.

Comment: @K.Davis Thank you for being persistent. I see what you are saying and clarified my original ask. Also there can be line breaks between AG156, Rose, + and Red.

Comment: @Kantoboy Okay, to solve the line break issue, try this pattern: `(?:.|\n)*(AG156(?:.|\n)*?red)`. Here's the [new regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HJYISX/3) showing line breaks.